# Spring Data REST: "no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value"

Tags: java, spring, java-8, spring-data-rest, lombok

When I use Lombok in my Spring Data REST application to define complex types like:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data

@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOK")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private Person author;

    // ...
}
```

with a Spring Data REST controllers like:

```
@RepositoryRestController
public class BookRepositoryRestController {

    private final BookRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public BookRepositoryRestController(BookRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,value = "/books")
    public @ResponseBody PersistentEntityResource post(
        @RequestBody Book book,
        PersistentEntityResourceAssembler assembler) {

        Book entity = processPost(book);

        return assembler.toResource(entity);
    }

    private Book processPost(Book book) {
        // ...
        return this.repository.save(book);
    }
}
```

I get an ugly error:

```
no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value
```

from Spring Data REST's use of Jackson with a Book POST like:

```
curl -X POST 
     -H 'content-type: application/json' 
     -d '{"title":"Skip Like a Pro", "author": "/people/123"}'
     http://localhost:8080/api/books/
```

The de-serialization error happens when Jackson tries to resolve the `/people/123` local URI which should resolve to a single, unique `Person`. If I remove my `@RepositoryRestController`, everything works fine. Any idea what's wrong with my REST controller definition?

Comment: Hey Jan, why are you using suppressConstructorProperties = true in AllArgsConstructor ?

Lombok dosumentation says: 'If set to true, then lombok will skip adding a @java.beans.ConstructorProperties to generated constructors. This is useful in android and GWT development where that annotation is not usually available.'

It seems that you don't fall in the recommended cases. What happens if you remove this configuration?

Comment: Please check @Data annotation in Lombock. It generates equals and hash code.

Comment: @avi613 -- unfortunately, Jackson's deserialization triggers the above error without `@AllArgsConstructor(suppressConstructorProperties = true)`  -- this is likely a Lombok bug.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the `@RepositoryRestController`, change the type of the `@RequestBody` argument from `Book` **to `Resource<Book>`**:

```
import org.springframework.hateoas.Resource;

    // ...

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,value = "/books")
    public @ResponseBody PersistentEntityResource post(
        @RequestBody Resource<Book> bookResource,             // Resource<Book>
        PersistentEntityResourceAssembler assembler) {

        Book book = bookResource.getContent()
        // ...
    }
```

and in the `Book` entity definition modify the `AllArgsConstructor` annotation to be: `@AllArgsConstructor(suppressConstructorProperties = true)`.

See [Spring Data REST #687](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-687) for more information.

Comment: I am exposing my Repositores with @RepositoryRestResource   (as spring-data-rest  HATEOAS Resources)    I do not have any RepositoryRestController.   But I get the same error. How can I work around it?

Comment: @Robert -- it is likely the same fundamental problem: Jackson cannot de-serialize your data; but, the solution will be different for your case. I suggest you open a new question with all the details...

Comment: @Robert -- you might also read the [Domain Object Representations section in the Spring REST reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#representations).

Comment: @Robert did you ever find a solution to this when using \@RepositoryRestResource ?