# Deserialize json string value to entity object

Tags: json, rest, spring-boot, entity, deserialization

I want my Rest webservice to create an object in it's rest repo that takes another pre-made Object of another type as a parameter in JSON form. However, I fail to guess on how I should name it in JSON format as it doesn't want to deserialize it for me.

Here's the Object I put in its repository first (no problems there):

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    private String username;

    @OneToOne
    private tOrder tOrder;

    public User() {
    }
    ...
}
```

Here is The object I fail to make due to not finding the prior made object:

```
@Entity
public class TaxiOrder implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    @OneToOne
    private User user;

    public TaxiOrder() {
    }
    ...
}
```

Here is how I try to create the Order object tries to take the User object as input:

```
{
    "user" : "/user/1"
}
```

And here is what I got in response:

```
Failed to read HTTP message: 
  org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not 
  read JSON document: Can not construct instance of 
  lv.emils.taxi.model.entity.User: no String-argument constructor/factory 
  method to deserialize from String value ('/user/1')
```

I need to call it in some slightly different other fashion, but I fail to figure out how exactly. I also don't know for sure if this is even a possible feature in @OneToOne relations, but I know it's possible in @ManyToOne.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Data REST: "no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40986738/spring-data-rest-no-string-argument-constructor-factory-method-to-deserialize)

Comment: I'm doing this without Hateoas though. This also deals with a OneToOne relationship rather than ManyToOne.